# MapPolyline.Path.Add doesn't work

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

I used this code for my app:

```
var line = new MapPolyline();
line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
line.StrokeThickness = 2;
line.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(lat,long));   //<== this
line.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(lat, long));  //<== and this
MyMap.MapElements.Add(line);
```

I used Windows phone 8.1 
At the marked locations receive this error:

> 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopath' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopath' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What to do to work??

P.S. I have using `Windows.Devices.Geolocation;`

Comment: What is the `line` variable declared as?  Is it supposed to be the `_polyline` or did you just forget to include the declaration for that variable?

Comment: My mistake. Not _polyline just line. Even changing

Answer (score 2):

That's right. You have to generate the list separately and pass it using the constructor:

```
List<BasicGeoposition> positions = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
// Now add your positions:
positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition(){ Latitude = lat, Longitude = long});   //<== this
positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition(){ Latitude = lat, Longitude = long));  //<== and this
Geopath path = new Geopath(positions);
var line = new MapPolyline();
// Set your path
line.Path = path;
line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
line.StrokeThickness = 2;
MyMap.MapElements.Add(line);
```

I know - it's a bit tricky. But I think the purpose is that you can't manipulate the path once the polygon is drawn on the map.